# How to convert number start with 0 to string equivalent of the value?

Tags: javascript

I want to convert a number start with 0 to string equivalent of the value.

If I run

```
var num = 12;
var int = num.toString();
console.log(int);
```

it logs 12 as expected but if I apply the `toString()` to a number start with 0 like,

```
var num = 012;
var int = num.toString();
console.log(int);
```

it logs 10, why?

Comment: Because if a number starts with `0` it is interpreted in [base 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal)

Comment: Now, if you want to convert it, since it's in the code and not input by the user, simply don't put that 0 before the number.

Comment: Not to detract from the answers, but if the simple fact that the number is octal was really what was being asked, there are a ton of duplicates. If the question is "how to convert an octal number to a decimal representation as if it wasn't octal", then that's a question worth answering. Can OP please clarify?

Comment: Also, try to develop your scripts in the "strict mode", which disallows some oddities of javascript, including this.

Comment: Is is interpreted as octal (base 8). Do yourself a service and start your files with ["use strict";](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) that removes some of the not so great parts of javascript.

Comment: If you need to ask a new question, do that. Please don't change your question to a completely new one.

Answer (score 5):

Number starting with 0 is interpreted as octal (base-8).

Comment: I can’t see how this is an answer to the OP’s question

Comment: OP wanted to know why in his first code snippet the output was 12 and in the second snippet it was 10. And how adding a 0 made a difference to the output.

Comment: But on his first statement and in the title he says that he wants to convert a number starting with a 0

Comment: 10 is the string equivalent of 012. But I get your point. It can also be interpreted as the OP wants the output to be '012' instead as mentioned in one of the comments - "how to convert an octal number to a decimal representation as if it wasn't octal"

Comment: knowing the use-case would clarify whether such a conversion is even necessary in the first place, or whether there are better ways of tacking the bigger problem

Answer (score 3):

In [sloppy mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Sloppy_mode) (the default) numbers starting with 0 are interpreted as being written in octal (base 8) instead of decimal (base 10). If has been like that from the first released version of Javascript, and has this syntax in common with other programming languages. It is confusing, and have lead to many hard to detect buggs.

You can enable [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) by adding `"use strict"` as the first non-comment in your script or function. It removes some of the quirks. It is still possible to write octal numbers in strict mode, but you have to use the same scheme as with hexadecimal and binary: `0o20` is the octal representation of 16 decimal.

The same problem can be found with the function [paseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/sv-SE/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), that takes up to two parameters, where the second is the radix. If not specified, numbers starting with 0 will be treated as octal up to ECMAScript 5, where it was changed to decimal. So if you use `parseInt`, specify the radix to be sure that you get what you expected.

```js
"use strict";

// Diffrent ways to write the same number:
const values = [
  0b10000, // binary
  0o20, // octal
  16, // decimal,
  0x10 // hexadecimal
];

console.log("As binary:", values.map( value => value.toString(2)).join());
console.log("As decimal:", values.join());
console.log("As ocal", values.map( value => value.toString(8)).join());
console.log("As hexadecimal:", values.map( value => value.toString(16)).join());
console.log("As base36:", values.map( value => value.toString(36)).join());
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is add `String` to the front of the number that is

```
var num = 12;
var int = String(num);
console.log(int);
```

And if you want it to look like this `0012` all you have to do is

```
var num = 12;
var int = String(num).padStart(4, '0');
console.log(int);
```